# Bokeh - multiple figures on same page

Tags: django, bokeh

I have a need to have 2 bokeh figures on a page. I need them to separate from each other. Currently I can have only one figure (with multiple plots using grid/rows/columns) but not with multiple figures.

Comment: can you show us some sample data and an example of your desired output?

Comment: Is this for a Bokeh server app? Is this for a standalone (non-server) Bokeh document? You haven't given nearly enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 9):

See the [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html) on how to append figures in rows or columns.

For an example on how to plot figures in the same row see

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("layout.html")

x = list(range(11))
y0 = x
y1 = [10 - i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i - 5) for i in x]

# create a new plot
s1 = figure(plot_width=250, plot_height=250, title=None)
s1.circle(x, y0, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

# create another one
s2 = figure(plot_width=250, plot_height=250, title=None)
s2.triangle(x, y1, size=10, color="firebrick", alpha=0.5)

# create and another
s3 = figure(plot_width=250, plot_height=250, title=None)
s3.square(x, y2, size=10, color="olive", alpha=0.5)

# put the results in a row
show(row(s1, s2, s3))
```

Likewise, you could put the results in a column using

```
show(column(s1, s2, s3))
```

Of course, you can combine the two to create a grid, so if you have a list of figures, say `graphs`, you could do something like

```
cols = []
row_num = 3
for i in range(0, len(graphs), row_num):
    r = row(graphs[i: i + row_num])
    cols.append(r)
show(column(cols))
```

Comment: I really loathe this SO canard about broken links. Answers on SO can just as easily become out of date when APIs change, bugs are fixed, or new features are added. And *worse*, unlike broken links which are easy to detect, there is no easily automatable way to detect such problems as "example code going out of date". When OSS devs put lots of effort into their docs precisely so that answers can be pointed to, then "RTFM" and a link to do the pointing is in fact the best possible answer.

Comment: I guess it is hard to prevent the whole site from filling up with links, but in case the answer is completely redundant, then indeed there is no point in this.. I agree @bigreddot

Answer (score 3):

```
Try having different script and div tag for the plots.

Example using Django:
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,show
from bokeh.embed import components
import random

**Define your View function this way**

def plot(request,*args,**kwargs):

    PLOT_OPTIONS = dict(plot_width=800, plot_height=300)
    SCATTER_OPTIONS = dict(size=12, alpha=0.5)
    data = lambda: [random.choice([i for i in range(100)]) for r in range(10)]
    red = figure(sizing_mode='scale_width', tools='pan', **PLOT_OPTIONS)
    red.scatter(data(), data(), color="red", **SCATTER_OPTIONS)
    blue = figure(sizing_mode='fixed', tools='pan', **PLOT_OPTIONS)
    blue.scatter(data(), data(), color="blue", **SCATTER_OPTIONS)
    green = figure(sizing_mode='scale_width', tools='pan', **PLOT_OPTIONS)
    green.scatter(data(), data(), color="green", **SCATTER_OPTIONS)
    script1, div1 = components(red)
    script2, div2 = components(blue)
    script3, div3 = components(green)
    context = {'script1':script1,'div1':div1,'script2':script2,'div2':div2,'script3':script3,'div3':div3}
    return render_to_response('graph.html',context=context)

**Then your Template should look like this:**

first load the dependencies inside the HEAD tag 

    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
    {{ script1 | safe }}
    {{ script2 | safe }}
    {{ script3 | safe }}

Inside the body or wherever you want to display the plots
 <div> {{ div1 | safe }} </div>
  <div> {{ div2 | safe }}  </div>
 <div>  {{ div3 | safe }} </div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.resources import CDN

x = [1,4,6]
y = [4,6,9]
plot = figure(width=300, height=300)
plot.line(x, y)
html1 = file_html(plot, CDN, 'my plot')
```

This way you can create multiple plots and insert them using standard jinja2 syntax

Like:

```
<h1> First plot </h1>
{{ html1 }}
<h1> Second plot </h1>
{{ html2 }}
```

More information you can find [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html)

Also you can try using [Tab Panels](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#tab-panes)